# Using flex, how can I keep yytext contents when EOF is reached and input is provided via YY_INPUT?

Tags: flex-lexer

When a scanner generated by [flex-lexer](/questions/tagged/flex-lexer) encounters end-of-file, it loses the content of `yytext[]` that was left there by `yymore()` calls in previous rules. This erroneous behavior ony happens if `YY_INPUT()` is redefined.

This may be a bug in flex, but it seems likely that there's something missing -- something else that a flex scanner definition should provide when it redefines `YY_INPUT()`.

I have tested using flex 2.5.35 on both Ubuntu 12.04.1 and on Windows 7. On both systems, the scanner loses the `yytext[]` content at EOF if the text to be scanned is provided via an explicit definition of `YY_INPUT()`.

Below is a sample flex scanner (`flex-test.l`) that is intended to read and print HTML comments, even if the last comment is unterminated. It works correctly when its input is provided via `yy_scan_string()`, but fails when its input is instead provided by an explicit definition of `YY_INPUT()`. In the sample code, `#if`'s are used to select between the `yy_scan_string()` and the `YY_INPUT()` implementations.
Specifically, the expected output:

```
Begin comment: <!--
More comment:  <!--incomplete
EOF comment:   <!--incomplete
```

appears if the scanner is built using

```
flex --nounistd flex-test.l && gcc -DREDEFINE_YY_INPUT=0 lex.yy.c
```

But if the scanner is built using

```
flex --nounistd flex-test.l && gcc -DREDEFINE_YY_INPUT=1 lex.yy.c
```

(changing the **=0** to **=1**), then this incorrect output appears:

```
Begin comment: <!--
More comment:  <!--incomplete
EOF comment:
```

Notice the absence of any comment text in that last line of output.

Here is the sample code:

```
/* A scanner demonstrating bad interaction between yymore() and <<EOF>>
 * when YY_INPUT() is redefined: specifically, yytext[] content is lost. */

%{
#include <stdio.h>

int yywrap(void) { return 1; }

#if REDEFINE_YY_INPUT

  #define MIN(a,b) ((a)<(b) ? (a) : (b))

  const char *source_chars;
  size_t source_length;

  #define set_data(s) (source_chars=(s), source_length=strlen(source_chars))

  size_t get_data(char *buf, size_t request_size) {
    size_t copy_size = MIN(request_size, source_length);
    memcpy(buf, source_chars, copy_size);
    source_chars += copy_size;
    source_length -= copy_size;
    return copy_size;
  }

  #define YY_INPUT(buf,actual,ask) ((actual)=get_data(buf,ask))

#endif

%}

%x COMM

%%

"<!--"          printf("Begin comment: %s\n", yytext); yymore(); BEGIN(COMM);
<COMM>[^-]+     printf("More comment:  %s\n", yytext); yymore();
<COMM>.         printf("More comment:  %s\n", yytext); yymore();
<COMM>--+\ *[>] printf("End comment:   %s\n", yytext); BEGIN(INITIAL);
<COMM><<EOF>>   printf("EOF comment:   %s\n", yytext); BEGIN(INITIAL); return 0;

.               printf("Other:         %s\n", yytext);

<<EOF>>         printf("EOF:           %s\n", yytext); return 0;
%%

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char *text = "<!--incomplete";

  #if REDEFINE_YY_INPUT
    set_data(text);
    yylex();
  #else
    YY_BUFFER_STATE state = yy_scan_string(text);
    yylex();
    yy_delete_buffer(state);
  #endif
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem has been in flex since, probably, forever. Basically, when flex gets an EOF from its current buffer, it processes the last token and then reinitializes the buffer, which effectively throws the current token away, even if it had been "saved" with `yymore()`. (It actually initializes the first two characters with `NUL`s, but that's sufficient to destroy it.) It then calls `yywrap()`, which has the option of providing another buffer (file).

This behaviour is usually harmless, because usually tokens are not allowed to span two different input files, but it would sometimes be nice to have the option. Not nice enough that anyone has bothered to fix it in the quarter century of flex's existence, though.

The unfortunate consequence is that you can't use `yytext` after you get an `EOF`, since the buffer reset has already been done even though there are no more input files. (`yyleng` isn't right, either; it has not been reset yet, and it has also been incremented with the `NUL` which triggered the EOF.)

There's a hack in the implementation of `yy_scan_string` which sets the newly-created buffer's `yy_fill_buffer` flag to 0, meaning that no attempt should be made to refill the buffer. That prevents the buffer reset, but does not protect `yyleng`, which is still incorrect. I'd consider the preservation of `yytext` pure luck, though.

If flex were being actively maintained, I'd suggest adding to the flex manual a comment that `yytext` and `yyleng` are undefined in an `<<EOF>>` rule, and maybe even think about fixing `yymore()` so that it allows spanning input buffers (or documenting the fact that it doesn't).

In short, you have two options:

1) Just use `yy_scan_string` or `yy_scan_buffer` (with all appropriate caveats), and hope that no-one reverts the hack which allows you to look at `yytext` in the `<<EOF>>` rule. I don't know how future-proof that hope is, but there's nothing forcing you to upgrade.

But you're probably better off with:

2) Use your own buffer to keep the accumulated token string.

Option (2) is not actually all that expensive; if the token strings are large, it is probably better than using `yymore` because flex really wasn't designed to handle large tokens. For comments, which can be quite sizable, you'll probably find that maintaining your own buffer will be a lot faster, as well as being a lot more predictable.

Comment: I was already strongly leaning towards solution 2. And now you've convinced me, since (as you say) a proper fix is probably not coming along anytime soon. Thank you for your helpful, knowledgeable, and insightful answer.